# Proving a real function is constant with Lagrange's or Rolle's

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

So i need to prove this function is constant and find the constant value

$$f:[2,\infty] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\\
f(x)=2\arctan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-\arcsin\left(\frac{4x}{x^2+4}\right)$$

So i normally used those two theorems in the title for proving similar statements.
But i'm not sure how to use it, so possibly my title is wrong, but i am open for suggestions.
Any help solving this would be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: It should be[-2,2] rather than [2,+\infty)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

One approach is to take the derivative and show it is zero.
$$
f'(x) = \frac{2}{1+(x/2)^2} \times \frac{1}{2}
      - \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{4x}{x^2+4}\right)^2}}
        \times \frac{d}{dx} \left[ \frac{4x}{x^2+4} \right]
$$
which does not involve any trig...

Another is to note that $f(0)=f(2)=0$, so you want to show that $f(x)=0$ or in other words,
$$
2\arctan(x/2) = \arcsin\left(\frac{4x}{x^2+4}\right)
$$
So take sines of both sides. RHS is easy and LHS is
$$
\sin \left(2\arctan(x/2)\right)
 = 2 \sin (\arctan(x/2)) \cos(\arctan(x/2))
 = 2 \frac{2}{\sqrt{x^2+4}} \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+4}}
$$
and you are done